# Can a data element be part of multiple data sets in DHIS2?

Tags: dhis2

In DHIS2, is it possible to have a data element be part of two different data sets? If so, will it lead to duplication of data values?

Answer (score 1):

A data element can be part of multiple data sets. A DHIS2 data value is linked to data elements, not data sets. The implication is that if you have a data element being part of multiple data sets and enter a data value for the first data set, then the data value will show up pre-filled in the other data set when you open it.

So there will not be duplication, but you will not be able to have different data values for that data element, as the data element will point to the same data value irrespective of which data set you open.

I am assuming that the same org unit, period and data set category has been selected in this scenario.